# Sorting result set by date attribute in 'vespa.ai'

Tags: vespa

How to sort a resultset by date (unixtime)?

```
search post {
    document post {
        field created type long {
            indexing: summary | attribute
        }
        field description type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }
    }
    rank-profile date inherits default {
        first-phase {
            expression: attribute(created)
        }
    }
}
```

curl:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data
    '{"yql" : "select * from post where description contains \"computer\";","ranking":"date"}'
    http://localhost:8080/search/ | jq .
```

The resultset is not sorted by 'created'.
And 'relevance' is always zero:

```
{
    "id": "id:post:post::1",
    "relevance": 0,
    "source": "content",
    "fields": {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For straight forward sorting on long attributes, it would be more efficient to use the [sorting/ordering](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/sorting.html) functionality rather than the more powerful, yet more expensive ranking framework.

As mentioned in the sorting documentation, it is recommended to use the built-in *unranked* ranking profile for queries with sorting/ordering. Also, I'm not sure the *ranking* alias is allowed when using the JSON query language - I believe you would need to use the full *ranking.profile* parameter which is nested in JSON.

Your `curl` would then look something like:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data
    '{"yql" : "select * from post where description contains \"computer\" order by created desc;","ranking": { "profile" : "unranked" } }'
    http://localhost:8080/search/ | jq .
```